# Partial derivative w.r.t. MSE in linear regression gives different results than textbook

Tags: partial-derivative, machine-learning, mean-square-error

I'm going over the book *Introduction to Machine Learning (Ethem Alpaydin)* to brush up on my ML basics and am facing some confusion over a derivation.

More specifically:

> There we used a single input linear model $g(x) = w_1 x + w_0$ where $w_1$ and $w_0$ are the parameters to learn from data. The $w_1$ and $w_0$ values should minimize:
> $$E(w_1, w_0\ |\ \mathcal{X}) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{t = 1}^N \left( r^t - (w_1 x^t + w_0) \right)^2$$
> Its minimum point cna be calculated by taking the partial derivatives of $E$ with respect to $w_1$ and $w_0$, setting them equal to $0$, and solving for the two unknowns:
> $$
> \begin{align}
> w_1 & = \dfrac{\sum_t^N x^t r^t - \bar{x}\bar{r} N}{\sum_t^N (x^t)^2 - N\bar{x}^2} \\
> w_0 & = \bar{r} - w_1 \bar{x}
> \end{align}
> $$
> where $\bar{x} = \sum_t^N x^t/N$ and $\bar{r} = \sum_t^N r^t/N$

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial w_1} & = \frac{2}{N}\sum_{t = 1}^N \left( r^t - w_1 x^t - w_0 \right) \cdot (-x^t)
\end{align}
$$

Setting $\frac{\partial E } {\partial w_1}$ to $0$ gives me:

$$
w_1 = \frac{\sum_t^N x^t r^t - w_0 \sum_t^N x^t}{\sum_t^N (x^t)^2}
$$

which is different from the textbook's derivation. Am I understanding something incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: Is $x^t$ supposed to represent "x transpose"? If so I would recommend using a capital "T", like $x^{\mathrm{T}}$

Comment: It's not transpose, it simply refers to the $t$th data sample.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the derivatives with respect to $w_{0}$ and $w_{1}$ and equating them to $0$ we have:
$$\frac{\delta E}{\delta w_{0}} = -\frac{2}{N}\sum_{t = 1}^{N}(r^{t} - w_{1}^{t}x^{t} - w_{0}) = 0$$
and:
$$\frac{\delta E}{\delta w_{1}} = -\frac{2}{N}\sum_{t = 1}^{N}(r^{t} - w_{1}^{t}x^{t} - w_{0})x^{t} = 0$$

From the first, it follows that:

$$\sum_{t = 1}^{N}r^{t} - Nw_{0} - w_{1}\sum_{t = 1}^{N}x^{t} = 0 \Rightarrow \widehat{w}_{0} = \frac{\sum_{t = 1}^{N}r^{t}}{N} - \widehat{w}_{1}\frac{\sum_{t = 1}^{N}x^{t}}{N} = \overline{r} - \widehat{w}_{1}\overline{x}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

where with $\widehat{w}_{0}$ and $\widehat{w}_{1}$ we refer to the estimated Least Squares estimators of $w_{0}$ and $w_{1}$ respectively. From the second, instead, it follows that:

$$\sum_{t = 1}^{N}x^{t}r^{t} - \widehat{w}_{0}\sum_{t = 1}^{N}x^{t} - \widehat{w}_{1}\sum_{t = 1}^{N}(x^{t})^{2} = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Using the condition derived in $(1)$ and $\sum_{t = 1}^{N}x^{t}$ $=$ $N\overline{x}$:

$$\sum_{t = 1}^{N}x^{t}r^{t} - N\overline{x}\overline{r} + \widehat{w}_{1}N\overline{x}^{2} - \widehat{w}_{1}\sum_{t = 1}^{N}(x^{t})^{2} = 0 \Rightarrow \widehat{w}_{1} = \frac{\sum_{t = 1}^{N}x^{t}r^{t} - N \overline{x}\overline{r}}{\sum_{t = 1}^{N}(x^{t})^{2} - N\overline{x}^{2}}$$

as indeed reported in your text. It can be noticed that, if you're already familiar with the concept of Variance and Covariance, the nominator of the latter is the covariance between $r$ and $x$, while the denominator is the variance of $x$ (if we were to divide both the numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{N}$, more precisely, where the two would then clearly cancel). Hope it clarifies.